# Не работают Inline buttons telegram (Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, button

Есть такой код:

```
reply_markup = {
            "inline_keyboard": [
                    [{
                           "text": "test1",
                           "callback_data": "test1"
                    }],
                    [{
                           "text": "test2",
                           "callback_data": "test2"
                    }]
            ]
    }
schedule_bot.send_message(last_chat_id, ':)', reply_markup)
```

И метод send_message:

```
    def send_message(self, chat_id, text, reply_markup):
        params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': reply_markup}
        method = 'sendMessage'
        resp = requests.post(self.api_url + method, params)
        return resp
```

По идее Телеграм бот должен ответить сообщением с текстом ":)" и кнопками в reply_markup, однако бот ничего не отвечает.Выдает ошибку Response[400].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение состоит в том, что заменить

```
params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': reply_markup}
```

на:

```
params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage'
# reply_markup = {"keyboard": [["Yes", "No"], ["Maybe"], ["1", "2", "3"]], "resize_keyboard": True}
# reply_markup = {'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'текст1', 'url': 'http://ya.ru'}]]}

reply_markup = {
    'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'текст1', 'callback_data': '123'}, {'text': 'текст2', 'callback_data': '1234'}]]}

data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': 'test url', 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
r = requests.post(URL, data=data, proxies=proxy)
```